# Is it possible to invalidate a value of a memoized function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that makes an HTTP request for a token, which will be used in future requests. This token is valid for an unspecified amount of time, probably a few hours or so.

```
  (defn request-app-token
    "Request an app token from FB. Useful for app-global actions, such as creating test users."
    [client-credentials]
    (-> {"client_id" (:client-id client-credentials)
          "client_secret" (:client-secret client-credentials)
          "grant_type" "client_credentials"}
         (form-encode)
         ((partial str fb-graph-api "/oauth/access_token?"))
         (client/get {:throw-entire-message? true})
         :body
         (json/read-str)
         (get "access_token")))
```

To me, this looks like a job for memoize: keep a copy of the token and reuse it, instead of requesting new tokens every time I need one.

```
  (def get-app-token (memoize request-app-token)) ; So beautiful :D
```

I just need to handle the case where the token expires. For that, I will invert control; take a function that needs a token, attempt to run it with the memoized token, and if that fails, then try it again with a fresh token.

```
  (defn with-app-token [client-credentials f]
    (try (f (get-app-token client-credentials))
         (catch Exception e ; I know I should be more specific here, I only want to catch HTTP 400 responses
           (f (request-app-token client-credentials)))))
```

This would sort of work, but after the first token expires, then all subsequent calls to `with-app-token` would make a request for a new token. I need some way to clear or invalidate the memoized return value of `get-app-token`.

I could write my own `memoize` function, with an `invalidate` function that clears a specific result, but I am wondering if there is already something in the language that is meant to handle this?

Comment: You might want to look at [`core.memoize`](https://clojure.github.io/core.memoize) which support this.

Comment: `clojure.core.memoize/memo-clear! f args` is exactly what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[clojure.core.memoize](http://clojure.github.io/core.memoize/) has what I need: a `memo-clear!` function. After requiring `[clojure.core.memoize :refer [memo memo-clear!]]`, the solution looks like this:

```
  (defn request-app-token
    "Request an app token from FB. Useful for app-global actions, such as creating test users."
    [client-credentials]
    (-> {"client_id" (:client-id client-credentials)
          "client_secret" (:client-secret client-credentials)
          "grant_type" "client_credentials"}
         (form-encode)
         ((partial str fb-graph-api "/oauth/access_token?"))
         (client/get {:throw-entire-message? true})
         :body
         (json/read-str)
         (get "access_token")))

  (def get-app-token (memo request-app-token))

  (defn with-app-token [client-credentials f]
    (try (f (get-app-token client-credentials))
         (catch Exception e ; I know I should be more specific here, I only want to catch HTTP 400 responses
           (memo-clear! get-app-token client-credentials)
           (f (get-app-token client-credentials)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`clojure.core.memoize` also has `ttl` function which supports caching the value for configurable time.

If the token is valid for 60 minutes, then you can use the ttl function as follows

```
(def get-app-token (memo/ttl request-app-token :ttl/threshold 3600000))
```